# Add data in the duplicate row in table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So let say I have a data date row in my table already and I enter another data with the same date. How can I add my other inputted dates to the duplicated row.
I'm doing this using jquery I'm also dynamically adding table row using jquery

Example:
I have this table

```
<tr>
<td>2014-10-18</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
```

then I have a modal form which has date picker and textbox let say I Pick the same data "2014-10-18" 
and added a new value 2. What I want is when I add this record I want my table row with the same date
"2014-10-18" be added the value 2 to the data 1

The output would be like this

```
<tr>
<td>2014-10-18</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So, to clarify, you'll never have two rows with the same date in the first cell? Or if a date is entered that already exists, it's row is added as well and any row that has that date in the first cell is updated?

Comment: *"I have this table"*.. that is not a table, that is a table row. *I want my table row with the same date "2014-10-18" be added the value 2 to the data 1"* - What is value 2? What is data 1?

Comment: another data in a row that i want to sum if I user input the same date. yes VCH I wouldn't have two rows with the same date. If the user input the same date that is already in the row it wil just be added on the row with the same date